# Wordpress - Contact Form 7, get email address

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I've created a form with Contact Form 7 Plugin, but forgot to add an email field in Message Body.

Does this plugin save the post data somewhere?

Comment: Contact Form 7 plugin doesn't save post data in db but other plugin provide save post data in db.
ex: https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/

Answer (score 0):

You can click on edit form and add email field shortcode(tag) in message body and click on the update of the form.